# Transforming unstructured data into a table or view

Tags: t-sql, structured-data

Currently I am working with a provider built SQL Server DB. This DB has data coming in from calls made through their system. The main table where data stored has 7 fields. 1 field is the Primary Key then 2 foreign keys, a couple datatime stamps and finally a massive field call "SergmentLog"

Within this field the data comes over unstructured. Here is an example of what the data looks like:

```
/20160219T154710.554-07/0?S=50&E=3512&CUTC=20160219T155235.662-07&1=100187177120160219&2=0&3=18823&4=user%20queue:icadmin&5=&6=Interact&7=|/20160219T154729.377-07/0?S=50&E=3504&CUTC=20160219T155235.663-07&1=100187177120160219&2=0&3=81592&4=user%20queue:icadmin&5=&6=LocalTransfer&7=%3cDetails%20TransferringUser%3d%22ICadmin%20-%22%20TransferringInteractionId%3d%22100187177120160219%22%20TransferredInteractionId%3d%22100187177120160219%22%20/%3e%0a&8=&9=2|/20160219T154850.970-07/0?S=50&E=3502&CUTC=20160219T155235.663-07&1=100187177120160219&2=0&3=55&4=&5=workgroup%20queue:Central%20Ops%202&6=LocalTransfer&7=%3cDetails%20TransferringUser%3d%22ICadmin%20-%22%20TransferringInteractionId%3d%22100187177120160219%22%20TransferredInteractionId%3d%22100187177120160219%22%20TransferredUser%3d%22Phoenix%20AZ%22%20/%3e%0a|/20160219T154851.025-07/0?S=50&E=3500&CUTC=20160219T155235.664-07&1=100187177120160219&2=0&3=1048&4=&5=&6=Queue&7=%3cDetails%20IVRAppName%3d%22Central%20Ops%202%22%20/%3e%0a|/20160219T154852.073-07/0?S=50&E=3502&CUTC=20160219T155235.664-07&1=100187177120160219&2=0&3=13344&4=&5=workgroup%20queue:Central%20Ops%202&6=Interact&7=|/20160219T154905.417-07/0?S=50&E=3504&CUTC=20160219T155235.664-07&1=100187177120160219&2=0&3=26202&4=user%20queue:icadmin&5=workgroup%20queue:Central%20Ops%202&6=LocalDisconnect&7=&8=&9=5
```

What I am told is that each "SegmentLog" could have multiple "Events", called "E=" within the SegmentLog field. Each event is broken out by the "|" pipe symbol. But prior to each even, there is a datatime stamp from the server, then a SourceID (called "S=") then finally the EventID (Called "E=")

After each EventID (number from 3500 - 3512) There will be Attributes numbering from 1-9 (Called "1=", "2=" etc.).

Keeping in mind that there may be multiple events per SegmentLog with the same EventID, and not all attributes will show in every EventID (IE E=3502 may only shows attributes 1-6, while E=3503 may show attributes 1-9) what would be the best way to structure this data into a table structure. The tools I have available are building complex search queries inside of a view or intermediate SSIS knowledge.

EDIT

I would like to see the data come out to something like this. But including all attributes:

```
DateTime                    Sequence  EventID  Attr1                  Attr3  
--------                    --------  -------  -----                  -----
/20160219T154710.554-07/0?  s=50      &E=3512  &1=100187177120160219  &3=18823
/20160219T154729.377-07/0?  S=50      &E=3504  &1=100187177120160219  &3=81592
/20160219T154850.970-07/0?  S=50      &E=3502  &1=100187177120160219  &3=55
/20160219T154851.025-07/0?  S=50      &E=3500  &1=100187177120160219  &3=1048
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what the datatype of the SegementLog column in your SQL Server table? Adding a create table statement as well may help to clarify this.

Comment: It is currently nvarchar(max). I am going to write how I would like it to show in an edit to the original post as well. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think this is what you're trying to accomplish.

To test this I added your sample line to a SQL Server table nvarchar(max) column:

```
if exists (select * from sysobjects where name='BigLongString' and xtype='U')
drop table dbo.BigLongString;
go

create table dbo.BigLongString
( 
 SegmentLog nvarchar(max)
);
go

insert into dbo.BigLongString (SegmentLog)
values ('/20160219T154710.554-07/0?S=50&E=3512&CUTC=20160219T155235.662-07&1=100187177120160219&2=0&3=18823&4=user%20queue:icadmin&5=&6=Interact&7=|/20160219T154729.377-07/0?S=50&E=3504&CUTC=20160219T155235.663-07&1=100187177120160219&2=0&3=81592&4=user%20queue:icadmin&5=&6=LocalTransfer&7=%3cDetails%20TransferringUser%3d%22ICadmin%20-%22%20TransferringInteractionId%3d%22100187177120160219%22%20TransferredInteractionId%3d%22100187177120160219%22%20/%3e%0a&8=&9=2|/20160219T154850.970-07/0?S=50&E=3502&CUTC=20160219T155235.663-07&1=100187177120160219&2=0&3=55&4=&5=workgroup%20queue:Central%20Ops%202&6=LocalTransfer&7=%3cDetails%20TransferringUser%3d%22ICadmin%20-%22%20TransferringInteractionId%3d%22100187177120160219%22%20TransferredInteractionId%3d%22100187177120160219%22%20TransferredUser%3d%22Phoenix%20AZ%22%20/%3e%0a|/20160219T154851.025-07/0?S=50&E=3500&CUTC=20160219T155235.664-07&1=100187177120160219&2=0&3=1048&4=&5=&6=Queue&7=%3cDetails%20IVRAppName%3d%22Central%20Ops%202%22%20/%3e%0a|/20160219T154852.073-07/0?S=50&E=3502&CUTC=20160219T155235.664-07&1=100187177120160219&2=0&3=13344&4=&5=workgroup%20queue:Central%20Ops%202&6=Interact&7=|/20160219T154905.417-07/0?S=50&E=3504&CUTC=20160219T155235.664-07&1=100187177120160219&2=0&3=26202&4=user%20queue:icadmin&5=workgroup%20queue:Central%20Ops%202&6=LocalDisconnect&7=&8=&9=5')
go
```

I then created a SSIS package to pull this data and parse it. The Data Flow Task looks like this:
[image: Data Flow Task]
 
The SQL statement in the OLE DB Source component is:

```
select 
      SegmentLog 
from 
      dbo.BigLongString;
```

The Script Component is a transformation, that has an asynchronous output:

[image: Inputs and Outputs Form]

If you expand the Output 0 tree you can see all of the columns added. The Attr* columns are all dt_wstr 500. I'm not sure how big these can get, so you might want to change the datatype. The rest of the columns I just make dt_wstr 50:

[image: Output Columns]

Here is the code for the Script Component. Make sure you build before exiting out:

```
 #region Namespaces
 using System;
 using System.Data;
 using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
 using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
 using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline;
 #endregion

 [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
 public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
 {
   private PipelineBuffer inputBuffer;

 public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
 {

    //length of blob
    int blobLen = 0;
    //the bytes of the blob
    byte[] webBlob = null;

    string webStr = null;

    string[] dateSplit = new string[] { "|" };

    //get blob length. Hardcoded to 0 since we only look at one column
    //in this example
    blobLen = (int)inputBuffer.GetBlobLength(0);

    //gets string from blob, hardcoded columnindex since we only have 1 column
    webStr = ConvertBlobToString((byte[])inputBuffer.GetBlobData(0, 0, blobLen));

    //holds value for dates in string
    string[] dates = webStr.Split(dateSplit, StringSplitOptions.None);

    //Loop through each date
    foreach (string date in dates)
    {
        //Parse out each attribute for a given date
        string[] attributes = date.Split('&');

        Output0Buffer.AddRow();

        //Loop through each attribute in date, you can remove the "&"+ if you do not need these in the values
        for (int i = 0; i < attributes.Length; i++)
        {

            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    Output0Buffer.DateTime = attributes[i].Substring(0, attributes[i].IndexOf('S'));
                    Output0Buffer.Sequence = attributes[i].Substring(attributes[i].IndexOf('S'), attributes[i].Length - attributes[i].IndexOf('S'));
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Output0Buffer.EventID = "&" + attributes[i];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Output0Buffer.CUTC = "&" + attributes[i];
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Output0Buffer.Attr1 = "&" + attributes[i];
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Output0Buffer.Attr2 = "&" + attributes[i];
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Output0Buffer.Attr3 = "&" + attributes[i];
                    break;
                case 6:
                    Output0Buffer.Attr4 = "&" + attributes[i];
                    break;
                case 7:
                    Output0Buffer.Attr5 = "&" + attributes[i];
                    break;
                case 8:
                    Output0Buffer.Attr6 = "&" + attributes[i];
                    break;
                case 9:
                    Output0Buffer.Attr7 = "&" + attributes[i];
                    break;
                case 10:
                    Output0Buffer.Attr8 = "&" + attributes[i];
                    break;
                case 11:
                    Output0Buffer.Attr9 = "&" + attributes[i];
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}

public override void ProcessInput(int InputID, Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineBuffer Buffer)
{
    inputBuffer = Buffer;
    base.ProcessInput(InputID, Buffer);
}

public string ConvertBlobToString(byte[] webBlob)
{
    //string to return
    string webStr = null;

    //get string from blob
    webStr = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(webBlob);

    return webStr;

}

}
```

Run the package and you should see the data parsed out as you expected in the Data Viewer:

[image: Data Viewer]